# Name of the class alphabetical index in ios. Like contacts index

Tags: objective-c, ios, object

Which is the name of the object class used to show an index of alphabet to find first occurrence in a tableview that starts with the selected letter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the [UITableViewDatasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) documentation, two related methods are described there. You can search by `section` to find it faster.